# How to do authentication in microservices?

Tags: node.js, express, microservices

I had an application developed in monolith architecture. It had all the authentication and authorization needed.My application front end is in angular and back end is in nodejs. I have jwt token generated from front end. Now I started implement micro services for each module but I don't know how to implement authentication and authorization so that all the services can use it. I read different article on it but still unable to find solution.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question with no single specific answer.  But, if you have multiple microservices that need to do "from scratch" authentication, then you'd probably need an authentication microservice that each of the other microservices could call to do auth verification.  Or, you build auth verification into the very early request arrival and auth info passes with the request object to any microservice that might need it.  Or, if everything the app does is ultimately just changing something in a database, you build an auth layer on top of the database microservice.

Comment: What about API gateway like a micro-service responsible for authentication and pass request to micro-service depending upon its route.

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to architect it.  With so little to go on in your question, I think your question is "off-topic" for stack overflow as there's no specific way to answer it that isn't very broad and full of opinion.

Comment: @jfriend00 Or you depend on digital signatures such as the case when you're using JWT tokens - the different services just need to share a secret/private key to verify the token but not if you use JWT simply as a cookie mechanism like the OP - generating it in the front end makes zero sense if you want to trust the token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below 3 step process need to be implemented for authentication & authorization solution :

1. You can create auth micorservice using spring oauth 2.0 which takes care of user authentication and generating the JWT token after successful authentication, Here existing monolithic code can be utilized upto some extent.
2. Now, Using API Gateway design pattern, JWT token can be authorized in each API call at API gateway layer only, Means We can validate the JWT on API gateway itself before passing it to the backend microservices.
3. Further, From API Gateway forward the coming Bearer token to the backend microservices where method level authorization can be taken care of.